# Algorithm for determining Y-axis labels and positions?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, charts

Given an array of y-values, like `[-3400, -1000, 500, 1200, 3790]`, how do I determine "good" Y-axis labels and positions them on a grid?

```
           ^
---(6,000)-|---
           |
---(4,000)-|---
           |
---(2,000)-|---
           |
<------(0)-+---------------------------------------->
           |
--(-2,000)-|---
           |
--(-4,000)-|---
           V
```

Comment: This is quite vague. Can you explain a little more? Also, if you just have a 1D array of values, why are you displaying two axes?

Comment: and, out of curiosity, why do this yourself? 100% (almost) of the tools capable of doing plotting handles this per default.

Comment: You really need to provide more information about what it's for, what constraints, how big this stuff is, etc. You haven't even said why the naive solution of just sticking the text at the given y-value doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it along the following lines:

1. Figure out the number of labels you want to have (`n`). The result may not have exactly this many labels, but it will be close. I'm going to have `n = 6`.
2. Decide, what numbers do you consider “pretty”. Do you only want to see steps like 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, … (in this case, pretty numbers are 1, 2 and 5) or are steps like 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, … good too? I'm going to consider only 1, 2 and 5.
3. Find out the minimum (`min`) and maximum (`max`) of the sequence, the rest of the numbers don't matter. (`min = -3400`, `max = 3790`)
4. Calculate the ideal, but ugly step between labels as `uglyStep = (max - min) / (n - 2)`. We subtract two for the label at the bottom and at the top. (`uglyStep = 1797`)
5. Calculate the order of magnitude of the `uglyStep` as `magnitude = 10 ^ floor(log10(uglyStep))`. (`magnitude = 1000`)
6. Pick the best pretty step, by multiplying magnitude by all pretty numbers and by ten. Then choose the number with lowest difference between it and `uglyStep`. This will be `prettyStep`. (`prettyStep = 2000`)
7. Compute the positions of the bottom and top label as `bottom = floor(min / prettyStep) * prettyStep` and `top = ceil(max / prettyStep) * prettyStep`. Note that `/` denotes normal mathematical division, not C-like integer division. (`bottom = -4000`, `top = 4000`)
8. Every number between `bottom` and `top` that is divisible by `prettyStep` is going to have a label. (`-4000, -2000, 0, 2000, 4000`)

This might need some modifications if you don't want `min` and `max` to be very close to `bottom` and `top`.

Also, it sometimes behaves somewhat oddly, e.g. for `min = 0` and `max = 3002`, it chooses `0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500`, but for `max = 3005`, it uses `0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000`.